# Highcharts js: get errors if there is a big point in a 3d series chart

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I get errors if there is a big point in a 3d series chart.

The below code is an example from the highcharts document.

http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/4dccq/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=4dccq

If I change the last value in the data array to 999 in the above code, I got the error in the Console of Chrome v54 and IE 11. But Firefox does not complain.

The changed code:
http://jsfiddle.net/4dccq/718/

Chrome reports:
Error:  attribute d: Unexpected end of attribute. Expected number, "M".

IE reports: 
SVG4601: SVG Path data has incorrect format and could not be completely parsed.

Thanks.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            margin: 75,
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 15,
                beta: 15,
                depth: 110
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                depth: 40,
                stacking: true,
                grouping: false,
                groupZPadding: 10
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4],
            stack: 0
        }, {
            data: [5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2],
            stack: 0
        }, {
            data: [7, 9, 8, 7, 5, 999], 
           // ****** I changed the last value form 8 to 999, and then got the error
            stack: 1
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a really curious error. I did some tests on your code example, and it seems the chart doesn't care much for values over 400. For example, if you added a `max` attribute for your y-axis and set it to 400, you can have values in your data up to 400 without any console errors. Any greater than that (say, 425), and the errors trigger. It's also worth noting the Highcharts demo of stacked 3D columns has the same errors: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-column-stacking-grouping/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a regression bug. It appeared in Highcharts 5.0.5, already fixed on master branch.

Use 5.0.4 version

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/5.0.4/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/5.0.4/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4dccq/719/

or github version:

```
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4dccq/720/